# How to force a webpage to think that it is in or out focus?

Tags: google-chrome, html, google-chrome-devtools, focus

I am trying to build a web app (to learn about WebSockets and adaptive behavior) that polls different social media sites and shows all the latest updates in one place. I want to make the page stop updating while out of focus, and then update again when in focus.

Testing the out of focus behavior has been very difficult, since I have to rely on logs to ensure that my app is working properly, and cannot have the window open in one monitor and work on the code in another monitor.

**My question is:**
Is there a way to "force" the tab to think that it is in or out of focus, like force element state in DevTools, but for the entire tab.

I am running Chrome on Windows 10. I could not find a way to do this using DevTools, and do not want to setup a whole testing framework just for such a simple thing.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Voting to move to StackOverflow, a programmer-oriented website.  You can see some other StackExchange sites at https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: You might consider creating a VM, opening the VM's browser to your site, leaving the VM cursor on your site, then switching back to your main PC with a keyboard command.  Or visiting the site on another nearby physical machine.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage That seems a little overkill.

Comment: If you have access to multiple PCs, the simplest answer is to visit the site from PC 2 and leave the tab in focus.  If you only have 1 PC, then you can make do with a VM.  Given that Keyboard + Mouse browsers only have 1 focus, and you need the focus for other actions on your development PC, I don't know of another way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open the [Command Menu](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/command-menu/).
2. Run the `Emulate a focused page` command.

If you create a [Live Expression](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/08/devtools#watch) and set the expression to `document.hasFocus()` you'll see that the page always thinks it's in focus after you run the `Emulate a focused page` command.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but is there a way to force a page to be out of focus, even if it is in focus? @Kayce

Comment: I can’t picture how that’s supposed to work. The page is out of focus even though you’re interacting with it? That sounds like a logical contradiction to me. If you provide a step-by-step example that should clear up any misunderstanding.

Comment: I envisioned something that allows me to inspect elements (using the element) picker without causing the page to momentarily be in focus. I understand if that is not possible, and the only solution that I have found is to use breakpoints and "freeze" the page.

Comment: The **Select An Element** button mentioned at the bottom of [this section](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/reference#select) doesn't focus the page. Neither does selecting the node from **Elements** panel > **DOM Tree**. Do those workflows work for you or do you need something else?

Comment: How is it different from the `:focus` option under force element state?