# How to force a webpage to think that it is in or out focus in FireFox?

Tags: firefox, focus, firefox-developer-tools

Note: This is the EXACT same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56299358/how-to-force-a-webpage-to-think-that-it-is-in-or-out-focus), but for FireFox.

Is there a way to "force" the tab to think that it is in or out of focus, like toggle pseudo classes in Developer Tools, but for the entire tab.

I am running FireFox on Windows 10. I could not find a way to do this using Developer Tools, and do not want to setup a whole testing framework just for such a simple thing.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Firefox DevTools this is not possible (as of Firefox 67), so I've created an [enhancement request to add this feature](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1556148).

Comment: Thank You for creating the request. I guess that I will stick to Chrome for development and run firefox for compatibility testing. I will look into the firefox source code, and try to implement the feature if I can.