# Looking for a way to force chrome tab to stay focused\active even though browser is minimized or switch to another tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for a way to trick/force the browser to keep a tab always active\focused, even if the user minimizes the browser itself or switches to another tab. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56299358/how-to-force-a-webpage-to-think-that-it-is-in-or-out-focus) and there's an option to make the tab simulate focus via the dev tools. I'm looking for a programmatic way to achieve the same effect, **without** forcing the actual view to return to that tab again. What are my options?

Comment: What is the effect you want to achieve?  It sounds like you want to bypass one of [these policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API#policies_in_place_to_aid_background_page_performance) - and the techniques you might try depend on which.  Some are listed toward the end of that section.

Comment: Let me guess ... you'd like to prevent that tab from closing or for it to be reborn (like the famous Phoenix) every time it is closed?
Do you want to prank your friend \ colleague or are we talking about an extension that you would seriously like to publish?
However, I don't think you can avoid a tab-switching flicker, at least not with the chrome extension APIs.

Comment: The only viable solution for this i found so far but extreme is installing a virtual machine with what i need and keep chrome on top and minimize the whole virtual machine which for chrome it is the only window on top so it stays alive